# Как использовать прокси сервер на ОС Windows

Tags: безопасность, proxy, ip, vpn

Возникло не понимание устройства процедуры подключения к интернету через прокси.

В качестве примера возьмем пять прокси с анонимностью `Elite`:

```
socks4://192.252.214.20:15864 - USA ~1300ms
socks4,socks5://208.102.51.6:58208 - USA Alexandria ~8000ms
socks5://192.111.139.165:4145 - Canada ~4500ms
socks4://50.197.210.138:32100 - USA Missouri City ~10000ms
socks4,socks5://192.111.129.145:16894 - Canada Toronto ~12400ms
```

Как мы можем заметить, разные протоколы и разные места подключения, также имеется существенный пинг.

> P.S. Скажу заранее, все прокси в этой статье, прошли валидность с помощью разных чекеров и парсеров.

Воспользуемся стандартным методом использования прокси на ОС Win10 - `Сеть и Интернет`.

С помощью комбинации клавиш `Win+X` появляется окошко в левом нижнем углу экрана, в котором необходимо выбрать `Сетевые подключения`.

После перехода по навигации, откроется окно `Параметры`, где натыкаемся на `Прокси-сервер`.
После свапа страницы, кликаем на `Использовать прокси-сервер`. Откроется доступ к текстбоксам, куда введем наши ip с портами.

> В качестве проверки ипишника, использовал сайт 2ip.

Теперь открываем браузер и заходим на сайт `2ip`.

[image: 2ip]

Как можем заметить, все плохо. Ну ничего страшного, у нас есть еще четыре ip адреса, проверим их.

> Не стану загружать остальные скрины, т.к никакой ипишник не сработал

После проверок всех пяти ip, мы не добились результата.
Возникает вопрос `Почему?`. И тут приходит мысль об использовании командной строки в качестве проверки, используется ли у нас прокси или нет.
Есть парочку команд, которые помогут проверить это:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:10809 bypass-list="localhost"
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="socks=127.0.0.1:10808" bypass-list="localhost"
```

> Первая для хттп, вторая для соксов

Заходим в `cmd` от имени администратора. После чего в параметрах подключаем прокси, а затем с помощью команды, посмотреть какой прокси стоит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Использовал http прокси в терминале, и поставил другой в параметрах

Как можно заметить, у нас разные прокси, хотя должны быть одинаковы. Поэтому идея с терминалом отпадает. Хотя бы пингует.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перейдем к самому интересному, возьмем ip с прозрачной анонимизацией.

```
http://150.136.4.250:3128 - USA Ashburn ~3500ms
```

ИИИИИ.....ВУАЛЯ!!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После таких махинаций, задаюсь вопросом, что не так я сделал. Может порты решают роль или анонимность, мб не так просто использовать анонимные ипишники. Люди добрые, помогите

Comment: Ну как минимум вы через «Параметры» не указывали, что нужно использовать протокол socks https://superuser.com/questions/1528185

Comment: Ну и да, прокси не умеют проксировать пинги, поэтому проверять работоспособность пингами нет никакого смысла